# Failed to connect Kafka with InfluxDB Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, influxdb, confluent-platform

I am trying to connect Kafka with InfluxDB.
This is my InfluxSink.properties, basically connector.

```
name=influxdb
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=influx
connect.influx.url=http://influxdb:8086
connect.influx.db=mydb
connect.influx.username=admin
```

but while running my connector I am facing this ***error***!

```
ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:126)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/utils/VersionUtil
    at com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector.version(InfluxDBSinkConnector.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:387)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:392)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.utils.VersionUtil
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 10 more
```

How can I remove this error. Suggestions needed!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the connector? Which version are you using, and which version of Kafka Connect? BTW it's much better to post the text of an error than a screenshot - it makes it easier for people to read, and helps others searching for similar problems :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt sure I will do this next time.... :) 
I am using Kakfa 2.13.
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect/kafka-connect-influxdb/0.1.0.9/source-code
downloaded jar file for connector from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not installed the connector correctly. The best route is to download it from [Confluent Hub](https://www.confluent.io/hub/) and install using the provided CLI, or unzip it into the Kafka Connect plugin folder (update `plugin.path` if needed).

I believe that InfluxDB connector has been removed by the author and replaced by [this one](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-influxdb). You'll probably find old copies of it or forks of the original repository lying around, but bear in mind they'll be several years out of date.